# Why is a negatively curved cone surface locally CAT(-1)?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Recently, I was reading a paper about the rigidity of negatively curved cone surfaces written by S. Hersonsky and F. Paulin. The authors said that a negatively curved cone surface is locally CAT(-1). But I don't know why.

A negatively curved cone surface is a surface $M$ endowed with a negatively curved cone metric, i.e. a smooth negatively curved Riemannian metric on $M-P$, where $P$ is a discrete subset of points on $M$, such that the completion of $M-P$ is $M$, and such that the cone angle at each singularity is greater than $2\pi$.

Comment: I assume that the metric has curvature less than $-1$ away from the cone points?

Comment: Note that if you cut a triangle into two thin triangles then it is thin and use it. See 9.3.4 here http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov-geometry/

Comment: @IgorRivin: the curvature is only strictly negative away from the cone points

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: how to prove that the new triangles are thin?

Comment: If the curvature is only assumed negative away from the cone points, then the result is false, since a Riemannian metric of curvature $-1/2$ is not CAT(-1).

Comment: @IgorRivin: Thanks. It's my mistake. The cone angle at each singularity should be grater than 2*pi. In this setting, a Riemannian metric of curvature -1/2 is not a cone metric.

Comment: @HuipingPan, I gave a ref, and yet for sure you have to assume that curvature $\le -1$.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, Thank you for your response and the ref.